# Traversing/recording matched predicates

Tags: prolog

I have a sequence of relations and I want to traverse them like a graph by recording the matches as I go. Say for example we have the following bizzare situation in a system that supports the following library functions for graphical manipulation:

```
image(raw).
image(png).
image(bitmap).
image(tiff).
conversion(tiff2bitmap, tiff, bitmap).
conversion(bitmap2png, bitmap, png).
conversion(png2raw, png, raw).
conversion(raw2bitmap, raw, bitmap).
conversion(png2tiff, png, tiff).

operation(crop, raw, raw).
```

So in the above example if we wanted to **crop** a **tiff**, you would have to do the following:

- convert the tiff to a bitmap
- convert the bitmap to a png
- convert the png to a raw
- use the crop operation
- convert the raw to bitmap
- convert the bitmap to a png
- convert the png to a tiff

For example, I could sit at the Prolog REPL and begin by asking what operation to convert a tiff to a bitmap with:

```
?- conversion(OP1, tiff, F1).
OP1 = tiff2bitmap,
F1 = bitmap .
?- conversion(OP2, F1, F2).
OP2 = tiff2bitmap,
F1 = tiff,
F2 = bitmap ;
OP2 = bitmap2png,
F1 = bitmap,
F2 = png 
... and so on
```

I want to be able to follow the following logic in Prolog but I do not know how to approach this. I think I need to use recursive rules and accumulators. We could work out how to crop a tiff using the following. I can solve the above manually like so:

```
/* the op is op in operation(op, x, x) */
conversions(Op, In, Steps) :-
  operation(Op, In, Out); /* no conversions necessary */
  conversion(C1, O1, O2),/* switch the incoming/outgoing to */
  conversion(C2, O2, O3), /* match successive conversions */
  conversion(C3, O3, O4), /* A->B, B->C, C->D */

  /* adding the matches C1-C3 to steps */
```

I would much prefer handle this automatically with accumulators and recursive rules but I do not know how to approach this.

Comment: Nope. I will look into the path search problem.

Answer (score 2):

After larsmans mentioned "path search", I searched and found a "[TekTips question](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1607508) ". From this, the following seems to work:

```
image(raw).
image(png).
image(bitmap).
image(tiff).
conversion(tiff2bitmap, tiff, bitmap).
conversion(bitmap2png, bitmap, png).
conversion(png2raw, png, raw).
conversion(raw2bitmap, raw, bitmap).
conversion(png2tiff, png, tiff).

operation(crop, raw, raw).

sconversions(End, A, End, [Conv]) :-
    conversion(Conv, A, End).

sconversions(End, A, B, Ops) :-
    conversion(X, A, C),
    sconversions(End, C, B, TailOps),
    Ops = [X|TailOps].

convert(Op, A, Path) :-
    operation(Op, In, _),
    sconversions(In, A, In, Path).

convertKeep(Op, A, Path) :-
    operation(Op, In, Out),
    sconversions(In, A, In, CPath),
    sconversions(A, Out, A, RPath), /* backward */
    append(CPath, RPath, Path).
```

Conversions disregarding the output format:

```
?- convert(crop, tiff, Ops).
Ops = [tiff2bitmap, bitmap2png, png2raw, crop]
```

The following shows the conversions:
    ?- convertKeep(crop, tiff, Ops).
    Ops = [tiff2bitmap, bitmap2png, png2raw, crop, raw2bitmap, bitmap2png, png2tiff]

I am new to Prolog, visitors would be better off studying larsmans' answer.

Answer (score 1):

When describing lists, always consider using DCGs. In your case, you only need the following:

```
conversions(S, S) --> [].
conversions(S0, S) -->
        { conversion(Op, S0, S1) },
        [Op],
        conversions(S1, S).
```

You can now use iterative deepening to try increasingly longer lists of operations exhaustively, until you reach a desired target state. For example, to get from `tiff` to `raw`:

```
?- length(Ops, _), phrase(conversions(tiff, raw), Ops).
Ops = [tiff2bitmap, bitmap2png, png2raw] .
```